# Calculate number of workdays PER MONTH from start_date and end_date

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I have a table that looks like this :

```
task_id | start_date |end_date
```

I want to calculate the number of workdays (just days from mondays to fridays , no holidays) per month.

for example : if a task took from 02-01-2022 to 05-02-2022 to be accomplished, i need the result to look something like this

```
task_id | january |february |march |april .............|december
1           21        4       0       0 ..........         0
```

Comment: You can try to use pivot

Comment: @D-Shih care to elaborate? i'm kinda stuck and i need help

Comment: OK I write a sample for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `generate_series` function to generate date during your start_date and end_date which we can easy to count then the condition aggregate function to make pivot.

[`extract`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) can get the month number or workdays(from Mondays to Fridays) by TIMESTAMP type, we can use that be count condition in aggregate function.

```
SELECT t1.task_id,
   count(CASE WHEN extract(isodow from dt) BETWEEN 1 AND 5 AND EXTRACT(MONTH from dt) = 1 THEN 1 END) january,
   count(CASE WHEN extract(isodow from dt) BETWEEN 1 AND 5 AND EXTRACT(MONTH from dt) = 2 THEN 1 END) february,
   count(CASE WHEN extract(isodow from dt) BETWEEN 1 AND 5 AND EXTRACT(MONTH from dt) = 3 THEN 1 END) march
    -- more months you can write
FROM T t1
CROSS JOIN generate_series(t1.start_date,t1.end_date,'1 day'::interval) dt
group by t1.task_id
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=341b4306463ed08148a8fa7a17506ccb)

Comment: @blablablabla No problem gald to help